# How to get a 64-bit long in both VS 2012 and g++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, g++

When I run the g++ compiled version of my program, the correct sum of 18510000000 is returned. When I run the VS 2012 compiled program, 1330130816 is returned. Can anyone explain why this might be and how to fix the code to work with both compilers?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 15000000; i++) {
        sum = sum + 1234;
    }
    cout << "sum = " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VS 2012 is compiling for a 32-bit integer and g++ is compiling for a 64 bit integer. Use an  __int64 or a long long, or whatever type your compiler needs to enforce a 64 bit integer.

Comment: `long long` will always be at least 64 bits wide.

Answer (score 1):

G++ uses 64-bit `long`, whereas Visual C++ uses 32-bit `long`.  Use `long long` if you want a 64-bit integer on these two compilers.  It may be better to use `int64_t` if you want to make sure it's 64-bit.

Comment: I wasn't able to get int64_t to work but thanks for the long long.

Comment: @Johnny: You need to include the `<cstdint>` (or `<stdint.h>`) header to use the `int64_t` and related integer types.

Comment: `int64_t` is **not** the answer; it does not exist on platforms that do not have a signed integral type that is **exactly** 64 bits wide. `int_least64_t` might be, or possibly `int_fast64_t`. On the other hand, `long long` will always be at least 64 bits wide, so is completely portable.

Answer (score -2):

If you have cross platform code with dependencies on the size of your types, for example for reading binary file formats or network messages, you can use static_assert to help you. For example,

```
static_assert(sizeof(sum1)==8 && CHAR_BIT == 8, "64-bit");
```